# Definition of interior point with quantifiers

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

Suppose that $x\in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $E\subset \mathbb{R}^m$.

**Definition.** We say that $x$ is an interior point of $E$ **iff** there is an open set $G$ containing $x$ such that $G\subset E$.

I was wondering can we write it in the following way using quantifiers?

$x$ is an interior point of $E$ iff $\exists G ((G\ \text{is open})\land (x\in G)\land(G\subset E)).$

If we take negation of this we obtain the following:

$x$ is NOT an interior pont of $E$ iff $\forall G((G\ \text{is not open})\lor (x\notin G)\lor(G\not\subset E))$.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Yeah, that works. The definition requires the existence of a set $G$ which satisfies 3 properties. The negation requires that all sets $G$ fail at least one property. This isn't special to topology/set theory/interiors - its more just logic.

Comment: @roundsquare, so what I wrote is correct?

Comment: yes, it is correct.

Comment: @roundsquare, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It works. Actually, think about it this way.

Say I want to prove that a point $x$ is not interior, i.e. it lives in the boundary.

Let's use your statement:
$$ \forall G((G\ \text{is not open})\lor (x\notin G)\lor(G\not\subset E)) $$

Clearly, I cannot construct sets $G$ that are always open. So, let's consider $G^{'}$ that are open.

Again, all open sets $G$ that do not include $x$ don't matter, as they do not give extra information. So let's consider $G^{'} such that $x \in G^{'}&

So far so good, I need to use open sets, that include $x$. So, the only thing that all my sets $G^{'}$ need to verify is that $G^{'}\not \subset E$, and that is precisely the intuitive way of thinking about proving that a point is not interior.

That is, a point $x$ is not an interior point of $E$, if all open set that include $x$, $G^{'}$ are not included in $E$.